# The string parameter in Jenkins don't work

Tags: jenkins, wdio-v5

When I configure the string parameter in Jenkins then call this parameter from the execute shell build step, it doesn't seem to consider this parameter because in the log nothing appear (where the yellow arrows are pointing):

[image: log]
[image: execute shell]
[image: parameter configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the parameter should be called with a different syntax in Windows and Linux.
  You can try  `--baseurl = %link84%` for Windows and `--baseurl = ${link84}` for Linux.

Source:
[How to add String parameter to Jenkins with optional checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284030/how-to-add-string-parameter-to-jenkins-with-optional-checkbox)